# Detect whether a PDF file is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open a pdf file in a new window and display the print dialog automatically.To do that i need to find when the file is fully loaded.
I tried win.Onload and document.readystate===completed, but both of them fire as soon as the window is loaded and does not wait till the PDF is loaded.Also cant use timeout since file size may differ.

Is there any DOM component  to find whether the PDF is fully loaded.

```
var win=window.open(printUrl);
win.print();
```

Any help on this??

Comment: You could first download the file in memory, and then open the data url, and add a small delay (as the file gets loaded from memory, it should then be shown a lot faster than from URL). As far as i know, the pdf plugin doesn't allow for checking wether a document is completely loaded or not.

Comment: Thanks .Have tried this ,but when i try to open very large files ,then i need to increase the delay accordingly.So it is not helping in real time scenarios

Answer (score 0):

We have a fix for this issue in Angular JS.

In HTML, you can have the following code

```
<button ng-click="printPdf('path_of_pdf')">Print Labels</button>
```

In JavaScript you need to write a function as follows

```
$scope.printPdf(path){

         var  myWindow = window.open(path, '', 'width=700,height=500');
         if(myWindow)
         {
            var original = Promise.resolve(myWindow);
            original.then(function(value){
              myWindow.focus();
            }).then(function(){
              $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                  myWindow.print();
                }, 2000);
              });
            });
         }

      }
```

It works as we expected. The print dialog box will be opened only when ​the PDF rendering has been completed.